# Public Initialization Vector?

Tags: ruby, cryptography

I'm using an OpenSSL cipher in Ruby to send text between a client and server and apparently it's a good idea to employ an IV, but for decryption on the server-side, I'm going to need that IV which was generated client-side. My question is will I run into problems sending the IV over the network? I don't know the first thing about cryptography, so I have no idea whether the IV can be used to decrypt the message or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IV is public information, it's totally fine to send it over the network. However, you should use a cryptographically secure random for every single encryption, especially if you are using CBC mode. Using a somehow predictable IV in a situation like that leaves your encryption vulnerable to certain kinds of attacks.

If you are completely new to cryptography and using `Cipher`, have a look at the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html), we added some information there that should help you getting started. It illustrates some best practices, among them is handling the IV correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The IV ensures that even if you were to encrypt two identical plaintexts using the same key, they produce distinct ciphertexts (because a new, randomly generated IV should be used for every encryption).

The IV cannot be used to decrypt the message without the key, and does not need to be transmitted securely, so it can be safely sent over the network along with the encrypted message.